# How to include html pages like home landing and other pages in index html in bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to create a web page so i need some idea of how each and every html page to be loaded in my index.html page..

As far as now I have included all the bootstrap packages and other css files in the index page.

Now how can I include or load all other pages in my index.html page??

please do help me if anyone knows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iFrame for load another page in same page.

```
<iframe src="www.facebook.com" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```